# How can I change the button that is in the view

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

I have a toggle button that is on the Viewer![alt text][1]

the problem is , when it turn on , How can recover the last status .
like even though the default value is false , how to set it true programmatically.

In the plugin.xml , the default status is true.

Answer (score 0):

If have contributed it via commands, you need to switch the state of the command (see HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState() method) and then call ICommandService.refreshElements() to update all the contributions for that command